# multiBarChart (nvd3) in rCharts is not displaying

Tags: javascript, r, bar-chart, rcharts

I am using [`rChart`](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/) library for generating javascript plots directly from R statistical package. I am trying to compute `multiBarChart` but the plot seems to be blank.

**EDIT**
What is more, none of examples from here displays on my computer:
https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/nvd3/examples.R
all examples are blank. Also some1 has a similar problem here and refers maybe to proxy:https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/624 .

This code worked for my on my other computer.

Any idea on what's going on and how to fix this?

Objects to reproduce this bug:

```
WhoAndWhere2Viz <- loadFromGithubRepo("cb754ba1e5b9542cdf982d1491c07099",
                   repo = "Museum",
                   user = "MarcinKosinski",
                   value =TRUE )
```

And a barchart itself

```
 library(rCharts)
 n1 <- nPlot( count ~ domena, group = "kto", data = WhoAndWhere2Viz,
                    type="multiBarChart")
       n1$addParams(dom = "myChart")
       n1$chart(color = c('brown', '#594c26', 'blue',  'green'))
 n1
```

My session info is

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pl_PL.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pl_PL.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
```

Comment: what is `input$type`? If you just want a `multiBarChart`, try `type="multiBarChart"`

Comment: Sory, this comes from input from shiny app I am building. It looks like all examples from here are blank on my computer https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/nvd3/examples.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this example in shiny works on every localization:

https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/5531732

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I can't view in browser unless I save it as an html file.

Try this:

```
   n1$save('test.html', cdn=FALSE)
```

Also, taking it a step further to shiny, see this example:

https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/5531732

Use renderChart2 instead of renderChart, though.

Comment: I used a lot of explanations from issues from their github repo and none of them worked unless I saved it with cdn=FALSE. https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues   renderChart2 doesn't seem to help. I've changed system ffrom ubuntu to windows and it worked ;]

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://rpubs.com/conniez/ufo_rchart) i got the solution

> Embed Option 1: Iframe Inline This first option is to embed the chart
>   as an inline iframe. It has the advantage of keeping the html
>   standalone, but isolating the chart from the html on the page, thereby
>   avoiding css and js conflicts. However, this feature is not supported
>   by IE and Opera.

```
n1$show('iframesrc', cdn = FALSE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 n1$addParams(dom = "myChart", "nvd3")
```